# DecryptMessage returning SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION

Tags: c++, encryption, xmpp, authorization, libstrophe

I have compiled libstrophe as a DLL for Windows.

During authorisation with the Jabber server `DecryptMessage()` is called three times as stanzas are passed back and forth. On the first two calls it returns `0 (SEC_E_OK)`, but on the third call it returns `0x80090302 (SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION)`. The **problem** is, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION` is not a valid return value. This happens both on Windows 7 and Windows XP.

I tried replacing the incoming encrypted string with garbage to see what was the return value, and it was `0x80090318 (SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE)`, so I know it's not simply a case of "garbage in - garbage out". I've also checked the JID is correct by logging in with the same JID using Pidgin.

Can anyone offer any enlightenment please?

Comment: As I understand when playing with libstrophe - main development line is using OpenSSL for TLS, so try to build it with OpenSSL, not with Windows Schannel TLS, because it is not well tested and buggy.

Comment: Thank you, vitalyster, that has fixed the problem, and I now have a working libstrophe DLL.