# Libstrophe windows TLS error

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, ssl, libstrophe

I'm having some problems with Libstrophe. I was able to make it work in linux (fedora) but seems that Windows is not going to be so easy.

Running basic.exe I have the following output (server was dukgo.com):

```
TLSS DEBUG QuerySecurityPackageInfo() success
TLSS DEBUG AcquireCredentialsHandle() success
conn DEBUG SENT: <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
xmpp DEBUG RECV: <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
xmpp DEBUG handle proceedtls called for proceed
xmpp DEBUG proceeding with TLS
TLSS DEBUG QuerySecurityPackageInfo() success
TLSS DEBUG AcquireCredentialsHandle() success
xmpp DEBUG Couldn't start TLS! error -2146893018
conn DEBUG SENT: </stream:stream>
xmpp DEBUG Socket closed by remote host.
xmpp DEBUG Closing socket.
DEBUG: disconnected
event DEBUG Stopping event loop.
event DEBUG Event loop completed.
```

The problem seems to be located in src\tls_schannel.c:331

```
ret = tls->sft->InitializeSecurityContextA(&(tls->hcred), &(tls->hctxt), name,
                          ctxtreq, 0, 0, &sbdin, 0,
                          &(tls->hctxt), &sbdout,
                          &ctxtattr, NULL);
    }

    if (ret == SEC_E_OK) {
```

ret value is -2146893018 instead of SEC_E_OK. I see some post about this problem and I changed to OpenSLL but has no use, still not working. Also in those cases DecryptMessage() was mentioned, I never reach that line in of code so far. [DecryptMessage returning SEC_E_UNSUPPORTED_FUNCTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204082/decryptmessage-returning-sec-e-unsupported-function)

If anyone have an idea about this I would be really thankful, I had trying to fix this for over a week and still nothing.

thanks, federico.

pd.: I have warnings like "warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in libeay32MTd.lib(LIBEAY32.dll); second definition ignored" I assume that openssl is working anyways